# Password problem on Ubuntu

Tags: password

Recently, I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a brand new computer without OS. I disabled the password at login. I typed my password in the terminal (with the command "su" to get administrator privileges) but it said it was incorrect.I tried several times but it didn't worked. I reinstalled Ubuntu 3 times but I had the same problem. Please help me :) Thanks

Comment: Exactly how did you use the command `su` in the terminal? Please add this bit to your question.

Comment: `su` requires a root account and that isn't enabled by default in Ubuntu. We use `sudo` with the same password for things that need elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

> with the command "su" to get administrator privileges

There is where you went wrong.

- "su" is old skool Linux where you use a root account. We are no longer using this as using "sudo" is considered slightly more secure (*)
- In Ubuntu we use "sudo -i" to get to a root prompt where the password you provide is the admin password (by default this is the password of the user you created the system with).

(*) someone trying to gain access to your machine needs to find out your username instead of knowing it is "root". "sudo -i" also logs every action done as your admin user. So if you have more than 1 admin you can see which of the 2 users it was. And there are a few more benefits (all slight improvements over using "root").